# Which files in home directory should not be shared between machines

Tags: 14.04, sync, nfs

I have two machines running the same version of Ubuntu (currently 14.04 64-bit); one is a desktop and one is a laptop. The processors, graphics cards, and screen resolutions of the two machines are different, but I'd like to share as much of the two home directories as possible. I realize that I shouldn't just mount, say, the desktop's home directory on the laptop using NFS or some other service, since certain files should remain local to each machine (.Xauthority, .gvfs/*, files containing info depending on screen size, etc.).

Has anyone cataloged a list of the files and directories that must remain local to different machines -- even if they share everything else? I'd like to use this to develop a Unison profile to help me keep these two machines in sync, ignoring the files that must remain separate.

Also, what about the related problem of keeping the installed software in sync? Is there an easy way to arrange that, if I install a package on one of the machines, the same package will (eventually) be installed on the other?

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/packages` gives you a list of installed software. `dpkg --clear-selections`
`sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages` should install packages from the list. You can build a script around that. Maybe you need to processs the package list from both machines first to identify software that is only installed on one of both. You can then make a unified packages list to contain everything.

Comment: I've seen this suggestion before. It would probably be helpful for the first clone of my desktop to my laptop, but less helpful, I think, for keeping the two in sync as new software is added to both machines. Something like Unison, which could detect that packages were either added or removed since the last sync and propagate just those changes to the other machine, would be better.

Comment: I never user unison, but I am using svn a lot, so I guess both could work. The trick is to figure out if a packet was intentionally removed, and needs to be removed from the other system, or if the other system installed this package and you need to install it now as well. You might need three files that you periodically process: packages.old with the result of last run (no need to synchronize), then a freshly generated packages list, and the current packages.remote of the other machine.

Comment: Do a `diff` between packages.old and packages to find out what was added/removed, and apply these to the packages.remote. Then overwrite packages.old with packages.remote, and use that list to set your selections. Sync packages.remote with the other machine afterwards/

Answer (score 0):

if they share the same architecture (32/64 bit) then everything except the /sys /system and /root partitions can be shared, the drivers kept in /bin and /usr/bin won't conflict under normal circumstances, and the exact same installed binaries can be run on machines with different resolution/specs

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? I was speaking about home directories only, but even there it seems that syncing all files would cause problems. I mentioned .Xauthority and .gvfs, but I imagine that there would also be problems with .dbus, .ecryptfs, .local, and others, but I'm not sure, which is why I'm asking.

Outside of home directories, I don't think you could share all of /etc (e.g., /etc/hostname) or /var (e.g., /var/log/*).